# 2/3 of iPod 6 display is transparent gray

Tags: ios, display, ipod

2/3 of my iPod 6 display turned transparent gray. The gray color is transparent and you can still see and interact with the contents in the area. Sometimes it is transparent gray with transparent white lines in the 2/3 area of the screen.

I have not done any damage to the device recently and would like to know if this is a software or hardware issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience this is almost certainly a fault with the display, most likely the flat flexible cable that runs from the screen to the main logic board.

As @tetsujin has suggested you can confirm this with a screenshot, if the screenshot is showing the same issue then you should look to restore the iPod using iTunes.

If the image doesn't show the grey then you should be looking to replace the screen on the device, either through an Apple Store or Authorised Service Provider https://checkcoverage.apple.com.

Alternatively if it is out of warranty or you cannot access an Apple service provider then you could try self repair, through a site like iFixIt.com.

Comment: I checked with the screenshot and it does seem to be a hardware issue.

Answer (score 1):

Take a screenshot [home & power buttons] & view it on another device.

If it's hardware, the issue won't be on the screenshot.